# Iterating items over items in a list

Tags: python, list

```
a=['aaaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccc']
```

I want my final output to look like this:

```
abcabcabcaba
```

NOTE: I would prefer not to import any additional packages.

Comment: zip takes any number of elements?

Comment: No, zip can take more if needed.

Comment: Zip does not work if you got different sized elements.

Comment: @lohi just updated with an approach without imports

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a=['aaaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccc']
b = zip_longest(*a, fillvalue="")

>>> print("".join(sum(b, ())))
abcabcabcaba
```

**Update: no packages**

Can loop in the range of the longest string:

```
m = max([len(x) for x in a])
b = [x[i:i+1]  for i in range(m) for x in a]
>>> print("".join(b))
abcabcabcaba
```

Comment: I'd probably use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(b)` over `sum(b, ())`, especially if we're already importing `itertools`

Comment: it's an option, why not

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
''.join(char for tup in itertools.zip_longest(*a) for char in tup if char)
```